# Displaying field in a view from a related model in Rails

Tags: model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-3.1, view, models

I have three models, Employee, Assignment, and Store.

Employees have many Stores through Assignments, and Stores have many Employees through Assignments.
(Assignments link Employee and Store together via foriegn keys)

Employees can only have one current assignment to a store.

What I'm trying to do in the Employee's index view is to display the employee's currently assigned store name (name is a field in the Store model).

How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your relations are set up in the usual way, use [`includes`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-multiple-associations) to eager-load the associated records:

```
@employees = Employee.includes( :stores => :employees ).all
```

Then in your view you'll have access to `@employees.stores[n].name` (`.stores` is a collection because you said Employee `has_many :stores, ...`).